# edit and Update records using reference id

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

i have table with multiple records in a field name Comments... with my aspx code the data in comments column gets inserted in three rows with different requirementcommentid but the field comment will remain same 
to retrieve distinct i used this query

```
SELECT distinct (
                 select top 1 requirementcommentid 
                 from Requirementcomment 
                 where requirementcomment=rc.requirementcomment 
                 and fcr.SectionID in(
                                      SELECT sectionid 
                                      FROM [dbo].udfGetSectionID_allComYear(2151)
                                      ) 
                 AND fcr.FirmID = 20057
                 ), 
       rc.IsRejected, 
       fcr.SectionID,
       rc.UserID,
       rc.RequirementComment,
       convert(varchar(25), dateadd(hour, -5, rc.InsertDate),101) as InsertDate,
       Department.DeptName,
       FirmUser.DepartmentID,
       rc.FirmComplianceYearID 
FROM RequirementComment rc 
INNER JOIN FirmComplianceRequirement fcr ON fcr.FirmComplianceRequirementID = rc.FirmComplianceRequirementID 
INNER JOIN FirmUser ON FirmUser.FirmUserID =rc.UserID 
INNER JOIN Department ON Department.DeptID = FirmUser.DepartmentID WHERE rc.IsRejected = 1 
AND fcr.SectionID in(SELECT sectionid FROM [dbo].udfGetSectionID_allComYear (2151))
AND fcr.FirmID = 20057 AND rc.RequirementComment!=''
```

if i want to edit this distinct comment and update it.how can i do this... as only one comment row get edited remaining two rows value in field comment remain the same...!

i want remaining data to be updated automatically  if i clicked on edit and updated only single record

Comment: So, say you have a 3 comments as "test comment", and you want to change all three to "Test Comment changed". Right?

Comment: yes....but ion gridview i have selected only distinct (top 1)... so that i can see only one Test Comment to Edit ... but if i edit this i want it to be changed in databse also with rest two ... i mean Test Comment ---T Comment in gridview but in database it must changed to remaining two that is 1) T Comment 2) T comment 3) T Comment

Comment: You will need to show the code you have already. All you need is an update with where clause.

Comment: is possible if i copy requirementcommentID column values to Refid Column ?? using that Reference i can update all the Comments ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can not solve this with a procedure when storing, or in .NET, consider to use a trigger. I have made a generic example, since your example code is a bit complex :)

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_TriggerTable
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , ID2 INT NOT NULL
    , Comment VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

GO

INSERT INTO TMP_TriggerTable
SELECT 1, 'asd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'asd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'asd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'asd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'asd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'asd'

GO


CREATE TRIGGER TRG_TMP_TriggerTable ON TMP_TriggerTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    WITH InsertedIDPriority AS
    (
        --Handle if more than one related comment was updated
        SELECT Prio = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY ID)
        , ID
        , ID2
        , Comment 
        FROM INSERTED
    )
    UPDATE t SET Comment = i.Comment FROM TMP_TriggerTable t
    JOIN InsertedIDPriority i ON 
    t.ID2 = i.ID2 --Select all related comments
    AND t.ID != i.ID2 --No need to update main column two times
    AND i.Prio = 1 --Handle if more than one related comment was updated

END

GO

UPDATE TMP_TriggerTable SET Comment = 'asd2' WHERE ID = 1

/*

SELECT * FROM TMP_TriggerTable

--Returns--
ID  ID2 Comment
1   1   asd2
2   1   asd2
3   1   asd2
4   2   asd
5   2   asd
6   2   asd
*/
```